# OpenGL segfault in glDrawArrays

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glut, glew

I have a C++ code that runs on a remote linux box doing math computations. I am accessing the linux machine from an M1 Mac using XQuartz (X window terminal). I would like to be able to display plots of the data in real time. I made one correction thanks to an earlier response, but now I crash at the glDrawArrays function.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>

GLuint vaoid[2];
GLuint vboid[2];

void init()
{
  glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glShadeModel (GL_FLAT);
}

void display()
{
  glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor3f (0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glLineWidth(3.0f);
  glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<100; ++i)
    glVertex2f(i*6, 300+100.*cos(i*2.*M_PI/100));
  glEnd();
  glBindVertexArray(vaoid[0]);
  glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 3); // <-- segfault here
  glBindVertexArray(0);
  glEnd();
  glFlush();      
}

void reshape (int w, int h)
{
  glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
  glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity ();
  gluOrtho2D (0.0, (GLdouble) w, 0.0, (GLdouble) h);
}

void createPoints(void)
{
  float vertices[6] = {100., 100., 400., 100., 400., 500.};
  glGenVertexArrays(1, vaoid); 
  glBindVertexArray(vaoid[0]);
  glGenBuffers(1, vboid);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboid[0]);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6*sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glBindVertexArray(0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)     
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);    
  glutInitWindowSize (600, 600);
  glutInitWindowPosition (100,100);
  glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; 
  glewInit ();
  createPoints();
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're segfaulting because you haven't loaded OpenGL functions and are basically calling a weakly linked (but unloaded) function (`glGenVertexArrays` in this case). To fix that, use a loader like GLEW or GLAD. Also see [Load GL Functions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions) and [OpenGL Loading Library](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) for more info.

I wouldn't sweat over Apple's actions. If you do end up creating a larger code base, you could introduce API abstractions so that it doesn't matter whether OpenGL does become deprecated in the future or not.

Comment: After using the GLEW loader, the segfault moved to glDrawArrays. Unfortunately, that is a Mac issue because it runs fine if I do a remote access from a Ubuntu machine. It only fails when I try to run it from an xterm on a Mac using XQuartz. My guess is that it's not able to access the GPU like it's supposed to.